# Angular ng-repeat not detecting changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `ng-repeat` to iterate over a json response via `http.get()`. Inside the `success()` callback i run a for-loop to create a new array which should be handled by another `ng-repeat`.

Code:

```
$http({
   method: "GET",
   url: "xxx",
   headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
   }
   }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

     $scope.onboardings = data.d.results;
     var counter = {};

     for (var i = 0; i < $scope.onboardings.length; i += 1) {
           counter[$scope.onboardings[i].Company] = (counter[$scope.onboardings[i].Company] || 0) + 1;
         }

     $scope.onboardingCompanies = counter;
     console.log($scope.onboardingCompanies);
})
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in onboardingCompanies">
    <p>{{item.key}}</p>
    <p>{{item.value}}</p>
</div>
```

So I need the ng-repeat to detect changes in `$scope.onboardingCompanies`. I know there is some async trouble here.

`console.log($scope.onboardingCompanies)`:

```
Object {Monjasa A/S (FRC): 35, C-bed BV: 2, Monjasa DMCC: 1, Monjasa Pte: 4, Monjasa SA: 9…}
```

Any advice?

Comment: ng-repeat keeps track of the object at all times, if there's any update on the array you are iterating on - even while the data received is async. Please console.log your object and the data received.

Comment: Since the data that you iterate through is an object - not array (which is also an object), in this case you could do something like:
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
  <td> {{key}} </td> <td> {{ value }} </td>
</tr>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is wrong: Angular doesn't give you an object with `key` and `value` attributes, it gives you them separately:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in onboardingCompanies">
    <p>{{key}}</p>
    <p>{{value}}</p>
</div>
```

The form you used `ng-repeat="item in onboardingCompanies"` angular will attempt to iterate over an array, but as the object isn't an array the result will be empty.